# Данные не дабавляютя в базу данных, а ошибок не выводится

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
  // include "../php/connect.php";
  $name_foto = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $description = filter_var(trim($_POST['description']),
  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if($_POST['portraits'] == "portraits") $portraits = "портрет";
  if($_POST['landscape'] == "landscape") $portraits = $portraits."пейзаж";
  if($_POST['сity'] == "сity") $portraits = $portraits."городской";
  if($_POST['сloseup'] == "сloseup") $portraits = $portraits."макросъемка";



  if($_POST['format'] == "r1") $foto_form = "jpg";
  if($_POST['format'] == "r2") $foto_form = "png";
  if($_POST['format'] == "r3") $foto_form = "raw";





  $mysql = new mysqli('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root','','fotosite');
  $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `foto` (`name`, `description`, `catigorie`, `extension`)
  VALUES('$name_foto', '$description', '$portraits', '$foto_form')");
  $mysql->close();





  $path = '../img/foto/';
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'):

    // Загрузка файла и вывод сообщения
    if (!@copy($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $path . $_FILES['picture']['name'])):?>
      <script>alert("Не удалось добавить фото");</script><?php
      exit();
       else:
        if ($name_foto == ''): ?>
          <script>alert("Добавте имя файла");</script>  <?php
          exit();
          else:
              if ($description == ''): ?>
                <script>alert("Добавте описание файла");</script><?php
                 exit();
              else:
                if (($_POST['portraits'] != "portraits") and ($_POST['landscape'] != "landscape") and ($_POST['сity'] != "сity") and ($_POST['сloseup'] != "сloseup")):?>
                  <script>alert("Выберете ...");</script><?php

                else:
                  echo "string";

endif;endif;endif;endif;endif;
```

Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Код php документа выше. Причем с регистрацией на сайте все работало. Переменные создаются нормально у всех есть значения(проверял)

Comment: проверяйте результат выполнения query и выводите сообщения об ошибках, если они возникают ( http://www.php.su/mysqli_error ). В текущей ситуации попытка понять ошибку сравнима с гаданием на кофейной гуще. Кроме того _никогда_ не вставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса, _всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку параметров https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Спапсибо сайчас попробую

Comment: ААА... мои глаза...

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать ) не ругайте! Я проверил ошибок не выводиться при соединении.

Comment: при соединении то ладно, главное после query проверьте что он вернет и если это не true, то печатайте ошибки

Comment: Я проверил что будет если вывести  $mysql и там много ошибок

Comment: И я дико туплю как проверить true или нет

Comment: посмотрите примеры по ссылке что я дал ( http://www.php.su/mysqli_error ) `if (!$mysqli->query("SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}`

Comment: я попробовал вывелась ошибка что он не понял что такое а

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предположил, что сейчас что-то не так с БД, возможно для какого-то из полей таблички foto неверно указан тип данных.
Я взял ваш код и вставка в БД у меня работает. Проверял так.

```
$name_foto = "name_foto";
$description = "description";
$portraits = "portraits";
$foto_form = "raw";
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'user','pswd','stackoverflow');
$q = $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `foto` (`name`, `description`, `catigorie`, `extension`)
VALUES('$name_foto', '$description', '$portraits', '$foto_form')");
var_dump($q);
var_dump($mysql->error);
$mysql->close();
```

В итоге в Базу добавляется запись, а var_dump'ы выводит следующее.

```
boolean true
string '' (length=0)
```

Соответсвенно надо видеть что у вас var_dump($mysql->error);

Comment: ок а где посмотреть

Comment: Я смотрю прям в браузере. Открываю страницу со скриптом. У меня локально путь до вашего скрипта выглядит вот так http://localhost:8888/PHP2_2/my/stackoverflow/question_1066916.php

Comment: Второй вариант можно ваш скрипт вызывать в консоли и посмотреть, что возвращают вар дампы там. Вызывать надо так `$  php my/stackoverflow/question_1066916.php`

Comment: кстати при выводе переменной $mysql у меня пишет в переменной ошибки

Comment: mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $ [client_version] => 50012 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 1054 [error] => Unknown column 'catigorie' in 'field list'

Comment: я её сократил и если честно я не очень понял где посмотреть

Comment: string(0) "" это случайно не то

Comment: _Unknown column 'catigorie' in 'field list'_

Проверьте, у вас название колонки 'catigorie' в коде и в БД совпадают, так как ошибка говорит о том, что они судя по всему разные.

Comment: ой брееед все 100 раз проверил когда сам вписал сработало спасибо

Comment: Огромное Спасибо